# How can I group by Latest Date in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have an issue with grouping the latest date by metric.

Let me show you exactly what I mean, let's say I have this table:

| Instance | Date | MetricID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marc | 09/14/21 | 1 | 5 |
| Marc | 09/14/21 | 2 | 2 |
| Marc | 09/14/21 | 3 | 1 |
| John | 09/14/21 | 1 | 10 |
| John | 09/14/21 | 2 | 1 |
| John | 09/14/21 | 3 | 1 |
| Marc | 09/15/21 | 1 | 15 |
| Marc | 09/15/21 | 2 | 0 |
| Marc | 09/15/21 | 3 | 1 |
| John | 09/15/21 | 1 | 10 |
| John | 09/15/21 | 2 | 1 |
| John | 09/15/21 | 3 | 0 |

I want to group the instance so that I only get the latest date by Metric if the value is positive (>0).

So I want to have this:

| Instance | LatestDateMetric1 | LatestDateMetric2 | LatestDateMetric3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marc | 09/15/21 | 09/14/21 | 09/15/21 |
| John | 09/15/21 | 09/15/21 | 09/14/21 |

I already tried grouping by MetricID and Max(Date) but I got an error message.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:** I tried this code, It looks a bit like I want except It takes the value even if it is null and the result is by line not column.

```
 SELECT "Instance", "MetricID", MAX("Date") as "LatestDate"
FROM "API_Metric2"
GROUP BY "Instance", "MetricID"
```

This is the result I got:

| Instance | MetricID | LatestDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marc | 1 | 09/15/21 |
| Marc | 2 | 09/15/21 |
| Marc | 3 | 09/15/21 |
| John | 1 | 09/15/21 |
| John | 2 | 09/15/21 |
| John | 3 | 09/15/21 |

How can I make it so that it only takes the value if it is not null?

Comment: This is called a crosstab. The issue is that you don't know how many LatestDateMetric columns you might need. Try googling "crosstab". If you want further assistance, please tag the actual database you are using (SQL Server? Oracle?)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for your comment! I only need 3 LatestDate column so It won't be a issue. I googled crosstab and it looks like something I might need. I'll keep on trying. I'm using Zoho Analytics so it supports the most popular SQL like SQL Server, MySQL and Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT "Instance",
       MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 1 THEN "Date" END) as LatestDateMetric1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 2 THEN "Date" END) as LatestDateMetric2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 3 THEN "Date" END) as LatestDateMetric3
FROM "API_Metric2"
WHERE value > 0
GROUP BY "Instance";
```

Comment: Thanks it's almost perfect! The only issue is that it takes the NULL value, so all the date are 09/15/21

Comment: @nonamesry . . . I have no idea what your comment is referring to.  Your sample data has no `NULL` values.  I do notice the part about `value` being positive, so I added that in.

Comment: Ah sorry, when I meant null I meant is equal to 0. Your code is working; thanks again and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

you can pivote

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    'LatestDateMetric'+cast(MetricID as nvarchar) as MetricID, 
    max(Date) as Date,
    Instance as Instance
  FROM API_Metric2
  group by Instance,MetricID
) t 
PIVOT(
MAX(Date) 
FOR MetricID IN (
    [LatestDateMetric1], 
    [LatestDateMetric2], 
    [LatestDateMetric3])
) AS pivot_table;
```